# g++ and clang++ different behaviour with non-type argument in struct/class specialization

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, template-specialization

I try to understand meaning and implications of [14.5.5/8 of the C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf) (idem in [C++14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) and, I suppose, in C++17)

> The type of a template parameter corresponding to a specialized non-type argument shall not be dependent on a parameter of the specialization.

and, as usual, to understand who's correct between g++ and clang++.

The standard show the following example

```
template <class T, T t> struct C {};
template <class T> struct C<T, 1>; // error
```

and both g++ and clang++ give error.

So far, so good.

Let's complicate a little the example adding a type

```
template <typename, typename T, T>
struct foo { };

template <typename T>
struct foo<T, int, 1> { }; // compile

template <typename T>
struct foo<T, T, 1> { }; // error
```

Both g++ and clang++ compile the first partial specialization (the type of `1`, `int`, isn't a parameter of the specialization) and give error with the second one (the type of `1` is `T`, a parameter of the specialization)

So far, so good.

Let's introduce a template struct `bar` with an internal type that **doesn't** depend from the template parameter

```
template <typename>
struct bar 
 { using type = int; };
```

and the following program

```
template <typename>
struct bar { using type = int; };

template <typename, typename T, T>
struct foo { };

template <typename T>
struct foo<T, typename bar<T>::type, 1> { };

int main ()
 { }
```

it's compiled without error by g++ (tried in wandbox with 4.9.3, 5.5.0, 7.2.0 and head 8.0.0; with c++11, c++14 and, when available, c++17) but clang++ (3.9.1, 4.0.1, 5.0.0, head 6.0.0; c++11, c++14, c++17) give the following error

```
prog.cc:11:38: error: non-type template argument specializes a template parameter with dependent type 'T'
struct foo<T, typename bar<T>::type, 1> { };
                                     ^
prog.cc:7:34: note: template parameter is declared here
template <typename, typename T, T>
                                ~^
```

As usual: who's right?

clang++, that consider `1` dependent on `T` (when `typename bar<T>::type` is fixed as `int`) or g++ that doesn't relieve this dependencies?

For completeness I have to say that changing `bar` as follows

```
template <typename T>
struct bar { using type = T; };
```

so making the `bar<T>::type` dependant on `T`, nothing change: g++ compile without error, and clang++ give the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at it from the compiler's point of view.

```
template <class T, T t> struct C {};
template <class T> struct C<T, 1>; // error
```

For the specialization, the compiler doesn't know if `T` can indeed have a value of `1`, and so the specialization is invalid.

For

```
template <typename T>
struct foo<T, typename bar<T>::type, 1> { };
```

Who's saying that `type` is always `int`? You might think that it is obvious, but I could introduce a specialization of `bar` for one specific `T` so that `type` is a `std::string`:

```
template<>
struct bar<const volatile int> { using type = std::string };
```

Basically, your statement "*when `typename bar<T>::type` is fixed as `int`"* is wrong, it is not fixed.

Now what? The standard here says the same thing as for your first example, the specialization is ill-formed, because as your quote correctly states, the type of the non-type parameter depends on another (templated) type of the specialization, namely `T`, which is unknown. In that regard, clang is right, and gcc is wrong.